# unable to read the entire local/sessionstorage from protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to read the entire storage from protractor test cases but it returns null. I am able to read individual keys but not the entire storage. I also am able to do it from outside protractor test cases (regular javascript code).

```
  var getLocalStorage = function () {
        return browser.executeScript("return window.localStorage;");
    };
```

Comment: `var getLocalStorage = function () {
        return window.localStorage;
    };`  does not work?

Comment: the interface mapping won't let you, but you can dupe it into a pure object: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage))`

Comment: @lealceldeiro I don't think I can directly use window.localstorage in protractor. It has to be through browser.executeScript.

Comment: @dandavis I don't think I understood what you are saying . Can you please elaborate?

Comment: `var getLocalStorage = function () { return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage))};`

Comment: @dandavis where is localstorage defined?JSON.stringify(localStorage)

Comment: `window`, which is redundant.

Comment: @dandavis sorry but window.localstorage or localstorage doesn't work inside protractor test case. It has to be through browser.executeScript();